# Why slider in js isn't working for all elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying a lot to create slider in vanilla js on my own, but i get stack with the logic of it. I've tried if and loops but smth goes wrong and don't work at all.
What conditions do i need to make this slider work for all quotes?
Thank you in advance.

```js
const quotesBtnNext = document.querySelector('#quo-btn-next'),
        quotesBtnPrev = document.querySelector('#quo-btn-prev'),
        quotesParent = document.querySelector('.quotes-wrapper'),
        quotes = document.querySelectorAll('.quotes-wrapper .quotes-wrapper__quote'),
        dots = document.querySelectorAll('.quotes__scroll');

let quoteIndex = 1;

quotesBtnNext.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    quotes.forEach(nextQuote());
});
quotesBtnPrev.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    quotes.forEach(prevQuote());
});

function nextQuote(){
        quotes[quoteIndex + 1].style.display = 'block';
        quotes[quoteIndex - 1].style.display = 'none';
}

function prevQuote() {
        quotes[quoteIndex + 1].style.display = 'none';
        quotes[quoteIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes-wrapper">
            <div class="quotes-wrapper__quote quotes-first">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris quis nostrud nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Jhone Due, Photographer</p>
            </div>
            <div class="quotes-wrapper__quote">
                <p>haha text</p>
                <p>Abraham Due, Photographer</p>
            </div>
            <div class="quotes-wrapper__quote">
                <p>another text</p>
                <p>David Due, Photographer</p>
            </div>
            <div class="quotes-wrapper__quote">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris quis nostrud nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Lora Due, Photographer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You didn't create any element with "#quo-btn-next'" & "#quo-btn-prev"

Comment: It looks like you might be accessing an array out of bounds here. You need to make sure that the element you are trying to access is in the bounds of the array. `quotes[quoteIndex + 1]` You need to make sure that `quoteIndex + 1` is greater than or equal to 0 and no greater than the array length minus 1